# Add or edit package in Cognos

Tags: cognos

I have some application, that use cognos as report engine. This application have some predefined packages for it's reports.

When I need to create report, I use tables and field in predefined packages, and everything is OK! 
But now I created my own table, and I want to make report for this table. But I don't see it in Cognos Report Studio, and I can't add it into default Ad-Hoc Query Layer. I tried to add SQL-query, but it also don't work.

How to edit predefined packages in Cognos. I think there need to be another utility, not Cognos Report Studio. But I don't know what utility, and I can't find any solution in IBM Help.

Comment: This would be up to the vendor of the software that is embedding Cognos as the reporting service.  In a standalone Cognos BI install, you would do this by adding the table in the Framework Manager model and then publishing your updated package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have error in configuration of SQL-query. Need to select source before SQL-check. Cognos don't need to have predefined packages to work with user-structures.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use IBM Cognos Framework Manager (if you have a Cognos BI Admin license, you'll also be licensed to use this), and edit the 'Model'. If the 'predefined package' you're referring to comes with models (e.g. the Cognos sample data is within the /webcontent/samples/models directory), then you can open these with Framework Manager and publish a new package with your update database structure.